# Script for retrieving datas -Oracle

Tags: oracle

I need to write script to capture the excel datas to a database table.Table name is B_USER

So select * from ..?
Any help will be appreciated

INSERT INTO B_USER
(SELECT U_ID,
U_NUMBER
FROM ????                   )

Comment: Little more information please - what do you plan to use to retrieve data from an Excel spreadsheet?

Answer (score 4):

SQL Loader is an Oracle utility which can be used to load data files into database tables. But I don't think it supports excel file. Please convert the excel file into CSV or any other delimited format, then use SQL loader. Please learn about it in the [SQL loader documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/part_ldr.htm#i436326).